# How to use 'greater than' while filtering with lodash an array of mongoDB collection?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, react-native, filter, lodash

How can i filter with "greater than" an array that has a collection from mongoDB?

All filters that i have done until now were constant, **like this:**

```
this.setState({ dataList: _.filter(this.state.dataList, { "Name": "Samuel" }) });
```

So, in this case, it will show me all items with name equals to Samuel.

What i'm trying to do is something that show me all items that are older than 'x'. I tried using $gt from mongoDB documentation **like this:**

```
this.setState({ dataList: _.filter(this.state.dataList, { "age": {$gte: 20 }) });
```

And i also did try using an function **this way**:

```
this.setState({ dataList: _.filter(this.state.dataList, ({age}) => age > 20) });
```

Input through insomnia:

```
{
    "name": "John",
    "age": 10
}
```

Output through console.log in the debug menu:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5e44ab5a38de8c2238750a22",
        "name": "Samuel",
        "age": "25",
        "__v": 0
      },
      {
        "_id": "5e44ac0d38de8c2238750a23",
        "name": "John",
        "age": "10"
        "__v": 0
      }
    ]
```

The expected result would be to just show Samuel's data, but it's not showing anything using `$gte` and using the function `({age}) => age > 20)` it's showing both.

**Code:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ScrollView, FlatList, View, Modal, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';
import { CheckBox, ListItem, Fab, Icon } from 'native-base';
import listStyle from './style';
import Card from '../Card/index';
import api from '../../service/api';
import _ from "lodash";


class Names extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = { header: null };
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            dataList: [],
            fullData: [],
            modalVisible: false,
            filterName: false,
            filteArge: false,
            loading: false
        };
    }

    UNSAFE_componentWillMount() {
        return api
            .get('/main')
            .then(responseJson => {
                this.setState({
                    dataList: responseJson.data,
                    fullData: responseJson.data,
                    loading: false
                });
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('server off');
            });
    }

    fName = async () => {
        if (this.state.filterName)
            await this.setState({ filterName: false });
        else
            await this.setState({ filterName: true });
    }
    fAge = async () => {
        if (this.state.filterAge)
            await this.setState({ filterAge: false });
        else
            await this.setState({ filterAge: true });
    }

    filter = () => {
        this.setState({ dataList: this.state.fullData });
        if ((this.state.filterName) === true) {
            this.setState({ dataList: _.filter(this.state.dataList, { "Name": "Samuel" }) });
        }
        if ((this.state.filterAge) === true) {
            this.setState({ dataList: _.filter(this.state.dataList, ({ age }) => age > 20) });
        }
    };
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <ScrollView >
                    <FlatList
                        data={this.state.dataList}
                        renderItem={({ item }) => <Card item={item} />}
                        keyExtractor={item => item._id}
                    />
                </ScrollView>
                <View>
                    <Modal
                        animationType="fade"
                        visible={this.state.modalVisible}
                        transparent={true}
                    >
                        <View>
                            <Text> Name= Samuel</Text>
                            <ListItem>
                                <CheckBox onPress={this.fName} checked={this.state.filterName} />
                                <Text  >Yes</Text>
                            </ListItem>
                            <Text> age > 20</Text>
                            <ListItem >
                                <CheckBox onPress={this.fAge} checked={this.state.filterAge} />
                                <Text >Yes</Text>
                            </ListItem>
                            <TouchableOpacity
                                onPress={() => {
                                    this.setState({ modalVisible: false });
                                    this.filter();
                                    console.log(this.state.dataList);
                                }}
                            >
                                <Text>Close</Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        </View>
                    </Modal>
                </View >
                <Fab
                    direction="up"
                    containerStyle={{}}
                    position="bottomLeft"
                    onPress={() => {
                        this.setState({ modalVisible: true });
                    }}
                >
                    <Icon name="md-add" />
                </Fab>
            </View >
        );
    }
}

export default withNavigation(Name);
```

I'm clueless about how should i handle this and make it work properly.

**Update:**

I found the error. Actually my model in my repository was unupdated and the age schema was a String. Now i've updated it and it's working fine.

Comment: The last solution should work. Does it throw an error? What does `dataList` look like?

Comment: @nipuna777 It still as if nothing happened. dataList is returning the data in the following format: 
`{name: 'samuel', age: '40'}`

Comment: Hmm.. that is weird. Can you update the post a full input and output for a dataList? Might be easier if you move the filter function before setState.

Comment: By full input I mean an array of data in and the value that is sent to the setState after filter.

Comment: @nipuna777 i was looking at the code at the input/output so i noticed that i'm inputing a Number type, as `{"Age":20}` for example, but the output is `{"age": "20"}`. Can this be the source of my mistake? Because i'm getting the data from a mongo database as JSON.

Comment: Could be. The key is case sensitive as well. Can you post the full input in the question?

Comment: @nipuna777 just did it

Comment: Given your input, the last filter function should work. Since it doesn't, we either getting the wrong input, or it's being called at the wrong time. 

We will need a bit more context on where you call this method to debug this. Can you post a reproducable code sample of the component you are using?

Comment: @nipuna777 Just update the question with the code in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setState` calls [can be batched](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous). Meaning that if you call `setState` on the same state value multiple times, the output will be unpredictable.

In your example, you are trying to set `dataList` twice in the same method. You can work around this issue wrapping the second set state in a callback:

```
filter = () => {
  this.setState({ dataList: this.state.fullData }, () => {
    if (this.state.filterName === true) {
      this.setState({ dataList: _.filter(this.state.dataList, { Name: "Samuel" }) });
    }
    if (this.state.filterAge === true) {
      this.setState({ dataList: _.filter(this.state.dataList, ({ age }) => age > 20) });
    }
  });
};
```

Or by only setting the state once:

```
filter = () => {
  let dataList = this.state.fullData;
  if (this.state.filterName === true) {
    dataList = _.filter(this.state.dataList, { Name: "Samuel" });
  }
  if (this.state.filterAge === true) {
    dataList = _.filter(this.state.dataList, ({ age }) => age > 20);
  }

  this.setState({ dataList });
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @nipuna777. I did tried your solution, but it didn't actually work, the filter seems to not work.

Comment: Oh okay, can you try the second solution mentioned here, and console log `dataList` right before the `this.setState({ dataList });` line and see what e result is? please note that I've modified that answer a bit

Comment: So, i was looking through the code, and i guess the problem is probably that the age is coming as a string. Can i tranform it back to a Number? Or retrieve the original model settings from the collection?

Comment: I found the error. Actually my model in my repository was unupdated and the age schema was a String. Now i've updated it and it's working fine. Your answer worked, thank you very much!